# Do CompletableFuture.runAsync(task) and Platform.runLater(()->new Thread(task).start()) have the same behavior?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application that **asynchronously scans and processes** files from a given directory.
I bind a `ProgressBar.progressProperty()` to the task's `progressProperty()`.

I have used `CompletableFuture.runAsync(task)` to run my task and it **works fine** without blocking the UI.

`Platform.runLater(()->new Thread(task).start())` works fine also.

My question is. Does `Platform.runLater()` above have any different behavior, apart from the return value?

Comment: `Platform.runLater()` places the task in the queue of the UI thread and it is executed when the turn comes (in other words, then the thread with the background task is started). Direct invocation of `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` starts the background task immediately. This is the main difference between the two approaches.

Comment: CompletableFuture.runAsync can reuse worker threads, while Platform.runLater(()->new Thread(task).start()) always creates a new thread. that is a very expensive operation. Also, the runLater is useless in this case.

Comment: The purpose of [`Platform#runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) is entirely different from [`CompletableFuture#runAsync(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)) (links go to documentation).

Comment: And in addition to @Clashsoft comment: The thread you create in `runLater` is a _non-daemon_ thread whereas `runAsync` uses the common `ForkJoinPool` which, at least be default, uses _daemon_ threads. That difference may or may not be significant to your application.

Comment: `Platform.runLater(() -> new Thread(task).start())` is essentially identical to `new Thread(task).start()`, other than a possible (and likely imperceptible, from the user perspective) delay in the task starting.

Answer (score 1):

`Platform.runLater` is intended to run something on the JavaFX thread.

So, what you are really saying with `Platform.runLater(()->new Thread(task).start())` is to ask the JavaFX thread to spawn a thread for you to run your task.  However, why wait?  You can just do that directly without the JavaFX thread involvement by doing: `new Thread(task).start()`.  This is slightly faster as you donot need to wait for the JavaFX thread to get around to running your task and spawning a new thread anyway.

`CompletableFuture.runAsync(task)` on the other hand runs your task on a standard shared thread pool (which usually has 1 thread per CPU).  If no thread is available because other heavy background processes are using up all the threads, then your task might be delayed for quite some time before it runs.

Spawning a thread when you need one is fine, but you might also want to look into using a `ThreadPool`.